# Is it possible to track user interaction with flash outside of the SWF and from the browser?

Tags: jquery, flash, tracking, interaction

I have been tasked with tracking user interactions with a flash movie that contains several chapters. I need to track which chapters the user decides to watch. **But I have no access to the flash movie itself and I can not modify it**.

The movie loads in a modal. I do have access to the HTML page from which the modal is spawned.

This is a screenshot of the interface. There are 6 chapters. Users can select the chapters they want to watch. They can then click `Play Your Demo`. Alternatively there's a `Play All` button. I would like to track which chapters users select.

This can be easily done with flash, but this is not an option. I hope I can use jQuery on the page to monitor user clicks. I am inclined to say this is not possible though, since JS can not track events/interactions with the flash movie, but I could be wrong.

Any ideas are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Actionsript -> jS and js -> actionscript can send event to each other but you need to access both of them to make integration between

Comment: Pretty much my thoughts are to wrap the flash file in a Div, use the mousedown function to capture events, and use coordinates to match where the user mousedowned at within the SWF File. Then have a response based on their X,Y mousedown, and send that to whatever needs to track it, _gaq.push, database write, etc.

Comment: Just as an aside... I feel really bad for you @Mohamad, that sounds like a terrible task to be assigned.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, wondering, would this not screw up if the flash movie resizes when the browser window is also resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to be able to use Javascript to detect when these events are happening inside the flash movie. Unless your flash movie is already programmed to send messages to javascript (via the `ExternalInterface` class as @Diodeus mentioned), you can't do this on the client side.

If the flash movie itself is broken up into several individual "child" swfs which are loaded dynamically from the parent SWF, then you might be able to gather some analytics from your server logs. For example, if the "Chapter 1" button loads a child SWF named "chatper_1.swf", your server should be logging that request.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: If you can modify the HTML page the content SWF is loaded into, you might be able to track Flash events by creating an ActionScript wrapper program, which *then* loads the original SWF into its own application domain.  Most of the mouse events and ADDED and REMOVED events bubble up in the display list, unless the programmer explicitly prevented it. So if you add event listeners to the loaded content, you may well be able to gain some introspection into what's going on inside of it.

Of course, it is impossible to say how much information you can gather from this, but it seems like it's worth a try.

Comment: interesting approach. This would require some working knowledge of flash, though. Assuming I wrapped the movie in a div and created a click-map based on click coordinates using jQuery, would this work even if the movie resized itself whenever the user resized their browser window?

Comment: Assuming that your click map is designed to accommodate resizing - yes.  Only you won't learn much from that map, except for a bunch of coordinates - there will be no semantic context.